# Restoring an .ics file into an Android phone calendar

Tags: android, api, calendar, adt

I have an ".ics" file(calendar file), which I am trying to restore into the phone calendar.
Surfing the web, I didn't find any useful and workable code in Android.
Can anyone help me in this issue ?

Best Regards

Comment: I'm not sure how to natively add it somehow on the phone, but you should be able to import an `.ics` file to your Google Calendar, which can then be displayed on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the .ics file using [ical4j library.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11794048/2219600)
2. Then you have to manually add the event to calendar.

Comment: Like you said,I've used the ical4j library, but I'm facing a problem concerning the insert of a birthday event. The following error occurs :" DTEND and DURATION cannot both be null for an event."
Note that my event is like:
**
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20371231T000000Z
SUMMARY:Tom Holo Birthday
DTSTART:19861226T020000
DTSTAMP:20131028T150131Z
UID:7+AndroidNabz**

and I am getting the ContentValues as :
**calendar_id=1 dtstart=535939200000 title=Tom Holo Birthday rrule=FREQ=YEARLY;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20371231T000000Z eventTimezone=Asia/Beirut**
Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Hey I am not too sure, what might be the problem. Sorry @AndroidNabz